# Setting and identifying when a cookie is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a minor but annoying bug.

```
<%=link_to "Home", controller: "homepage", action: "index"%>
<%if cookies[:session] == nil %>
<%=link_to "Sign Up", controller: "accounts", action: "new"%>
<%=link_to "Log in", controller: "accounts", action: "login"%>
<%end%>  
<%if cookies[:session] != nil%>
<%=link_to "Account", controller: "accounts", action: "show", id: cookies[:session]%>
<%=link_to "Sign out", controller: "accounts", action: "signout"%>
<%end%>
```

This is the navigation bar. It's supposed to check if an account has already signed in. If it has then it'll show the Account and Sign Up links, if it doesn't have a value it'll show the sign up and login in.
links.

```
def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      cookies[:session] = @account[:id]
      redirect_to action: 'show', id: @account[:id]
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

 def verify
    @checkaccount = account_params
    account = Account.find_by_username(@checkaccount[:username])
    if account != nil
      cookies[:session] = "test"
      if account[:password] == @checkaccount[:password]
        cookies[:session] = account[:id]
      end
      redirect_to action: 'show', id: account[:id]
    else
      redirect_to action: 'show', id: account[:id]
    end
  end

def signout
    cookies[:session] = nil
    redirect_to controller: 'homepage', action: 'index'
  end
```

This is my code to identify when accounts are signed in or signed out. When an account is signs out the cookies storing their session value should be nil, yet the navigation bar still displays the Account and Sign Out buttons as if the value weren't nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the cookie value as `nil` it will be stored as empty string `""` in the browser not as `nil` or `null`. So, you need to use `present` or `blank` instead of checking the value is `nil`.

```
<%=link_to "Home", controller: "homepage", action: "index"%>

<% if cookies[:session].present? %>
  <%=link_to "Account", controller: "accounts", action: "show", id: cookies[:session]%>
  <%=link_to "Sign out", controller: "accounts", action: "signout"%>
<% else %>
  <%=link_to "Sign Up", controller: "accounts", action: "new"%>
  <%=link_to "Log in", controller: "accounts", action: "login"%>
<% end %>
```